# Successful sites using Asp.NET and the Facebook API

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Are there any sites out there that have been built with asp.net and facebook api? I am looking for some ideas and inspiration for doing some social networking web programming. I did find some asp.net/facebook blog entries but still could not find any site that has successfuly done some work in this area.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the framework you create your ideas in pretty much irrelevant? It shouldn't make much difference if a site is made in ASP.Net, or Ruby on Rails, or PHP, or *etc etc etc*.

Why not look for *any* successful site using the Facebook API (regardless of implementation)? Or do you want ideas on how to implement things specifically within ASP.net?

Answer (score 1):

I found this through google:

[Gift List](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/08/05/giftlistr-asp-net-mvc-facebook-application.aspx)

Here are some links that mention a facebook .net wrapper:

[SilverLight and Facebook](http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2008/10/16/How-to-Build-Facebook-Applications-with-Silverlight-2-RTW-_1320_-Part-1-of-2.aspx)

[FaceBook .Net](http://www.nikhilk.net/FacebookNET.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly doable, here's an example:
http://apps.new.facebook.com/louisefy/, http://www.new.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=21805666590

And a blog post with a bit of explanation:
http://www.itu.dk/~friism/blog/?p=92